# Get Javascript to rollover the date for next month

Tags: jquery, html, date

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fDm2p/
Everything is in working order except towards the bottom the month is not rolling over and displaying dates that obviously do not exist. Can someone please help me modify my existing code to get this to work? I am using the TD class as the "add number"

Comment: That was the wrong jsfiddle, sorry. Updated with the correct one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/fDm2p/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#calcShptable td").each(function() {
        var theDate = new Date();
        var addNum = parseInt($(this).attr("class"));

        theDate.setDate(theDate.getDate()+addNum);

        myDate = (theDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + (theDate.getDate()) + '/' + theDate.getFullYear();
        $(document.createTextNode(myDate)).appendTo(this);
    });
});
```

Using `setDate` with a number that is too large will handle the rollover for you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you cannot just add the days to the getDate() function, but instead need to create a completely new Date object, adding the number of days to the getTime() representation of today:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var today  = new Date();
    $("#calcShptable td").each(function() {
        var addNum = parseInt($(this).attr("class"));
        var theDate = new Date(today.getTime() + (addNum * 86400000));
        myDate = (theDate.getMonth() +1) + '/' + (theDate.getDate()) + '/' + theDate.getFullYear();
        $(document.createTextNode(myDate)).appendTo(this);
    });
    });
```